# Format find output into one field

Tags: unix, find, cut

I am doing a find command to get items sorted by access time:

```
$ find . -printf "%A+\t%p\n" | sort -r
```

The output looks like this:

```
2020-05-05+06:00:55.5569719990  ./form.py
2020-05-05+06:00:55.5569719990  ./amazon.js
2020-05-04+12:48:24.8209719990  ./historical.py
```

However, I would like to only show the filepath and remove the timestamp after it's been sorted like that, so getting:

```
./form.py
./amazon.js
./historical.py
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
find . -printf "%A+\t%p\n" | sort -r | cut -d$'\t' -f2-
```

Or if you want to use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), you should use TAB as delimiter (if not, it breaks on files with spaces on filenames):

```
find . -printf "%A+\t%p\n" | sort -r | awk -F$'\t' '{print $2}'
```

Comment: @Giles -- thanks for this -- for the above would you suggest using `cut` or `awk` in your normal way of doing things?

Comment: Gilles not Giles. Yes, unless you have newlines in filenames (very rare cases)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`awk`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk) here if you want which will figure out the separator for you:

```
find . -printf "%A+\t%p\n" | sort -r | awk '{print $2}'
```

Note that it needs single quotes and fields are one-indexed.

Comment: What about files with spaces in filename ?

Comment: @GillesQuenot would the above not work in that case? Is `\t` the standard separator used on the `$ ls` command?

Comment: Yes, this solution doesn't work as-is if there's spaces

Comment: @GillesQuenot got it -- want to state in your answer where your approach works where mine would not, and then I can accept it?